# Moving zipped driver file from cd

Tags: wireless

Obviously,  I’m a total Newbie. I have a CD in my ex MacBook Pro,  the CD containing a zipped driver for a Brostrend wireless usb. How on earth,  and I’ve tried everything, can I move the zipped file into Home, or Downloads or anywhere but the CD. With thanks and baited breath

Comment: Insert the CD, locate the .zip file, drag the icon to the ~/Desktop, or wherever. Understand that the .zip file may be too old, or not appropriate for your current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A CD is a storage medium and it is automatically mounted when inserted in the optical drive tray and shown in Files file manager like any other storage media or device. From Files simply copy the zipped archive from the CD and paste it wherever you want.